# Add specific icon to react app that exists in material-ui but in a different color

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add an icon like this to my react app:

[image]

I see material-ui has a similar icon but it's yellow and I'm not aware that it can be changed. How can I add this?

Comment: `<WarningAmberIcon sx={{ color: "#cc0000" }} />` works for me.

Comment: What package is this in?

Comment: It's in this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/icons-material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<WarningAmberIcon sx={{ color: "#cc0000" }} />`

[This](https://npmjs.com/package/@mui/icons-material) is the package which must be installed.